# Kubernetes when to use secrets instead of configmap?

Tags: kubernetes

What are the differences between secrets and configmap in term of security?

In which cases would I want to use secret instead of configmap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Secrets are stored encoded and over time will [become more protected](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12742) (e.g. limited access, encrypted at rest, etc). Secrets existed before ConfigMap was created, so until recently it was common to store configuration data in secrets (e.g. [conf2kube](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/conf2kube)).

You should use secrets for sensitive data (database passwords, private keys) and ConfigMaps for non-sensitive configuration data.

Comment: it's just only encoded not encrypted so I don't see the 'security' advantage of secrets.

Comment: To be usable in your container, secrets must be decoded/unencrypted. So I suppose you are talking about when they are at rest in etcd storage. It is true that today there isn't a real difference, but that will change over time and secrets will automatically benefit from enhanced security while config maps will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly secrets are stored in tmpfs, an in memory file system, and are never persisted to a node file system.

Conversely they consume RAM.